# Ubuntu 12.04 : Uninstall boost installed from source

Tags: uninstall, source, boost

I installed boost 1.54 libraries on ubuntu 12.04, and it seems to conflict with my installation of libboost-all-dev, so i want to uninstall boost 1.54 libraries completely. How to uninstall the one installed from source?

Answer (score 34):

just looking at http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/01/9444.php
which says to delete `/usr/local/lib/libboost*` and `/usr/local/include/boost`

Comment: Wow. They really do not offer other less "manual" method.

Comment: This continues to be relevant for Boost 1.68.0 and Ubuntu 16.04.