# Uninstall boost library

Tags: 14.04, apt, uninstall, libraries, boost

I'm trying to uninstall boost library:

```
sudo apt-get purge libbboost-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libbboost-dev

sudo apt-get purge libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libboost-all-dev' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 219 not upgraded.
```

But `apt list --installed | grep boost` command shows me it still here.

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

libboost-atomic1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-atomic1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-chrono1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-chrono1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-context1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-context1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-date-time1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-date-time1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-exception1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-filesystem1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-filesystem1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-graph1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-graph1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-iostreams1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-iostreams1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-locale1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-locale1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-math1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-math1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-mpi-python1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-mpi1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-mpi1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-program-options1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-program-options1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-python1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]
libboost-python1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-random1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-random1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-regex1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-regex1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-serialization1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-serialization1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-signals1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-signals1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-system1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-system1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-test1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-test1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-thread1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]
libboost-thread1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-timer1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-timer1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-wave1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost-wave1.54.0/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost1.54-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libboost1.54-tools-dev/trusty-updates,now 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

This command shows nothing:

```
dpkg -L libboost-dev
dpkg-query: package 'libboost-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

And one more method:

```
ldconfig -p | grep boost
    libboost_wserialization.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_wserialization.so.1.56.0
    libboost_wserialization.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wserialization.so.1.54.0
    libboost_wserialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_wserialization.so
    libboost_wserialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wserialization.so
    libboost_wave.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_wave.so.1.56.0
    libboost_wave.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wave.so.1.54.0
    libboost_wave.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_wave.so
    libboost_wave.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wave.so
    libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.56.0
    libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.54.0
    libboost_unit_test_framework.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
    libboost_unit_test_framework.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
    libboost_timer.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_timer.so.1.56.0
    libboost_timer.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_timer.so.1.54.0
    libboost_timer.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_timer.so
    libboost_timer.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_timer.so
    libboost_thread.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.56.0
    libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
    libboost_thread.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so
    libboost_thread.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so
    libboost_system.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.56.0
    libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0
    libboost_system.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so
    libboost_system.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
    libboost_signals.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.56.0
    libboost_signals.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_signals.so.1.54.0
    libboost_signals.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_signals.so
    libboost_signals.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_signals.so
    libboost_serialization.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.56.0
    libboost_serialization.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.54.0
    libboost_serialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.so
    libboost_serialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so
    libboost_regex.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.56.0
    libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0
    libboost_regex.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so
    libboost_regex.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so
    libboost_random.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_random.so.1.56.0
    libboost_random.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_random.so.1.54.0
    libboost_random.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_random.so
    libboost_random.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_random.so
    libboost_python.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so.1.56.0
    libboost_python.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so
    libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0
    libboost_python-py34.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so
    libboost_python-py27.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.54.0
    libboost_python-py27.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so
    libboost_program_options.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.56.0
    libboost_program_options.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.54.0
    libboost_program_options.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so
    libboost_program_options.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so
    libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.56.0
    libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.54.0
    libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so
    libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so
    libboost_mpi_python-py34.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi_python-py34.so.1.54.0
    libboost_mpi_python-py34.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi_python-py34.so
    libboost_mpi_python-py27.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi_python-py27.so.1.54.0
    libboost_mpi_python-py27.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi_python-py27.so
    libboost_mpi.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so.1.54.0
    libboost_mpi.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_mpi.so
    libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.56.0
    libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.54.0
    libboost_math_tr1l.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1l.so
    libboost_math_tr1l.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_tr1l.so
    libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.56.0
    libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.54.0
    libboost_math_tr1f.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1f.so
    libboost_math_tr1f.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_tr1f.so
    libboost_math_tr1.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1.so.1.56.0
    libboost_math_tr1.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_tr1.so.1.54.0
    libboost_math_tr1.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_tr1.so
    libboost_math_tr1.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_tr1.so
    libboost_math_c99l.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_c99l.so.1.56.0
    libboost_math_c99l.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_c99l.so.1.54.0
    libboost_math_c99l.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_c99l.so
    libboost_math_c99l.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_c99l.so
    libboost_math_c99f.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_c99f.so.1.56.0
    libboost_math_c99f.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_c99f.so.1.54.0
    libboost_math_c99f.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_c99f.so
    libboost_math_c99f.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_c99f.so
    libboost_math_c99.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_c99.so.1.56.0
    libboost_math_c99.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_c99.so.1.54.0
    libboost_math_c99.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_math_c99.so
    libboost_math_c99.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_math_c99.so
    libboost_log_setup.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so.1.56.0
    libboost_log_setup.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so
    libboost_log.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.56.0
    libboost_log.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so
    libboost_locale.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_locale.so.1.56.0
    libboost_locale.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so.1.54.0
    libboost_locale.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_locale.so
    libboost_locale.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_locale.so
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.56.0
    libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so.1.54.0
    libboost_iostreams.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
    libboost_iostreams.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so
    libboost_graph_parallel.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph_parallel.so.1.54.0
    libboost_graph_parallel.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph_parallel.so
    libboost_graph.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_graph.so.1.56.0
    libboost_graph.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph.so.1.54.0
    libboost_graph.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_graph.so
    libboost_graph.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_graph.so
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0
    libboost_filesystem.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
    libboost_filesystem.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so
    libboost_date_time.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.56.0
    libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0
    libboost_date_time.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so
    libboost_date_time.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so
    libboost_coroutine.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_coroutine.so.1.56.0
    libboost_coroutine.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_coroutine.so
    libboost_context.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_context.so.1.56.0
    libboost_context.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_context.so.1.54.0
    libboost_context.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_context.so
    libboost_context.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_context.so
    libboost_container.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_container.so.1.56.0
    libboost_container.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_container.so
    libboost_chrono.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.56.0
    libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so.1.54.0
    libboost_chrono.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.so
    libboost_chrono.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so
    libboost_atomic.so.1.56.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.56.0
    libboost_atomic.so.1.54.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so.1.54.0
    libboost_atomic.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.so
    libboost_atomic.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so
```

I don't remembe how boost was installed and my OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

So my questions are:

1. What method should be used to detect presence of library in the system?
2. How to completely remove boost library?

**UPDATE:**

Seems I managed to do it like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/347894/266204), but not sure if it's good way and `apt list --installed | grep boost`, `ldconfig -p | grep boost` still show presence of boost:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libboost*
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/boost
```

Comment: It looks like you had boost 1.54 installed in `/usr` **and** boost 1.56 installed in `/usr/local`; you probably only removed the latter

Answer (score 0):

Take this with 100 mg of NaCl, because a grain may not be quite enough. I am not an expert on this subject. This may be worth considering:

I'd try installing it again, and then purging it. Might not work, but I can't see that it can hurt. If that fails, with trepidation you might try editing /var/lib/dpkg/status. Very carefully. And make a backup before you do, and be sure you have an alternate way to boot to restore the backup in case I lead you down a path to a totally borked system. To be real prudent, back up the system with fsarchiver first. I do that regularly. See post 3 here:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264110&s=dd16e1e6bd6cc6cd8773e1693230c80e&p=13222580#post13222580

That method (plus manually correcting the symlinks in /) worked for me when the 4.4.0-77 kernel kept sneaking in and breaking my system.